# Update rows with the same value

Tags: sql, oracle

So we got two tables:

```
Table A (ID, NAME)
1, 'NAME1'
2, 'NAME1'
3, 'NAME2'
4, 'NAME2'

Table B (ID, NAME)
NULL, 'NAME1'
NULL, 'NAME1'
NULL, 'NAME2'
NULL, 'NAME2'
```

How to update Table B with IDs from Table A, without getting single row subquery error?

Classic UPDATE won't work, single row subquery error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can number the rows for each name in both tables using the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function and then join based on name and row number and then use a `MERGE` statement to update the existing table correlating on the `ROWID` pseudo-column to uniquely match each row:

```sql
MERGE INTO table_b dst
USING (
  SELECT a.id,
         b.rid
  FROM   (
           SELECT id,
                  name,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY id, ROWNUM) AS rn
           FROM   table_a
         ) a
         INNER JOIN (
           SELECT ROWID as rid,
                  name,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY id, ROWNUM) AS rn
           FROM   table_b
         ) b
         ON a.name = b.name AND a.rn = b.rn
) src
ON (src.rid = dst.ROWID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET id = src.id;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Table_A (ID, NAME) AS
SELECT 1, 'NAME1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'NAME1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'NAME2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'NAME2' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Table_B (ID, NAME) AS
SELECT CAST(NULL AS NUMBER), 'NAME1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, 'NAME1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, 'NAME2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, 'NAME2' FROM DUAL;
```

Then, after the `MERGE`, table B contains:

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NAME1 |
| 2 | NAME1 |
| 3 | NAME2 |
| 4 | NAME2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DbytMLpv)

Answer (score 1):

If data really looks like that (meaning: `id` values in the 1st table represent a gapless sequence that starts with `1`), then such an update might do.

Before:

```
SQL> select * from ta;

        ID NAME
---------- -----
         1 name1
         2 name1
         3 name2
         4 name2

SQL> select * from tb;

        ID NAME
---------- -----
           name1
           name1
           name2
           name2
```

As there's nothing you can join tables on (`name` isn't enough), you have to "invent" something else - result returned by the `row_number` analytic function which will return gapless sequence values.

```
SQL> update (select ta.id   a_id,
  2                 ta.name a_name,
  3                 tb.id   b_id,
  4                 b.name  b_name
  5          from (select tb.id, tb.name,
  6                  row_number() over (order by tb.name) rn,
  7                  tb.rowid row_id
  8                from tb
  9               ) b join ta on ta.name = b.name
 10                          and ta.id   = b.rn
 11                   join tb on tb.rowid = b.row_id
 12         )
 13  set b_id = a_id;

4 rows updated.
```

After:

```
SQL> select * from ta;

        ID NAME
---------- -----
         1 name1
         2 name1
         3 name2
         4 name2

SQL> select * from tb;

        ID NAME
---------- -----
         1 name1          --> ID column is now populated
         2 name1
         3 name2
         4 name2

SQL>
```

Comment: If you're going to assume that table a is already sequentially ordered from 1 (so that a.id=b.rn works) you can skip everything and just update b.id = b.rn?

Comment: Better to apply row_number to both tables, partitioned by name, join on the name and new rn's, then update b.id?

Answer (score -1):

To update Table B with IDs from Table A without encountering a single row subquery error—given the challenge of non-unique `NAME` values and `NULL` `ID`s in Table B—you can use a technique involving common table expressions (CTEs) and the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function. This approach generates a temporary, unique sequence number for rows in both tables based on their `NAME` values, allowing for a precise one-to-one mapping during the update.

An example could be

```
WITH A_with_seq AS (
  SELECT ID, NAME, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY ID) as seq
  FROM TableA
),
B_with_seq AS (
  SELECT NAME, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as seq
  FROM TableB
)


UPDATE TableB
SET ID = A_with_seq.ID
FROM B_with_seq
JOIN A_with_seq ON A_with_seq.NAME = B_with_seq.NAME AND A_with_seq.seq = B_with_seq.seq
WHERE TableB.NAME = B_with_seq.NAME;
```

Comment: The final where clause will join all Name1's to all Name1's.

Comment: Doesn't execute: https://dbfiddle.uk/6w9S_7rZ

Answer (score -1):

We can do this using a merge statement like below,

```
MERGE INTO TableB
USING TableA
  ON  (TableB.NAME = TableA.NAME)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
 UPDATE 
SET TableB.ID = TableA.ID;
```

Comment: Doesn't Run : https://dbfiddle.uk/D5SkVBT3

Comment: My bad, didn't notice the duplicate record.